# Does InDesign convert all images to JPEG when exporting to PDF?

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, compression

When I'm exporting in InDesign,the compression settings say that I am able to change the dpi and chose the format of the compression.

Does this mean that if I select 72 dpi and JPEG format all the images in the document will be converted to this specification?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

All raster images are compressed according to the setting you choose. But downsampling is only done to images above the threshold you set.